# How to check if replication is done on read/write laravel postgresql connection and then proceed

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm facing delay problems between master and slave nodes replication process. Sometimes it's not happening quickly enough and I'm facing page errors like 404 not found and stuff like that. Is there a way to check if the replication process is done right after for example an INSERT query and then proceed?

Something like

```
$insert = DB::table('users')->insert([.....]);

if($insert->replicationStatus() == "done") {
    // PROCEED
}
```

**Laravel 8**

Comment: How is replication affecting your site. Are you using the slave server instead of the Master?

Comment: Laravel is doing everything - using Master server for INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE.. and Slave server for SELECT... But I'm facing problems like inserting and right after the insert being redirected to a page that should contain the data from the insert but the data didn't arrived yet in the slave server and I'm getting an 404 Not Found. The data appear after a page refresh!

Comment: Then you appear to have made the probelm for yourself, why are you using the slave for selects

Comment: I'm not using anything manually!!! Laravel is deciding what to use... Which node should be used for selects? I guess the read-only (slave) must be used.

Comment: I would expect there is some config that is making this happen

Comment: And 404 errors are HTTP errors, nothing obviously to do with a database access

Comment: You can't understand me. 404 is a HTTP error but it's thrown for a reason... The reason here is that the record I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "sticky" option: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#the-sticky-option

Comment: sticky option is working only for the CURRENT REQUEST CYCLE. It's not doing what you think it does.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no specific things in Laravel out-of-the box for it in that case. "Sticky" should solve most common cases, but in your case it doesn't work and you face with slave replication lag. I think you can go 2 ways:
1) Change the user interface to avoid immediate READ after WRITE. For example, you could pull the data in the same request cycle, or just wait a bit.
2) Optimize your cluster replication time on Postgres side.

Comment: I have brilliant idea. I'll create a route that is called something like "redirector" which will accept `next_url` parameter. The route will contain a loader and after 1-2 seconds it will redirect the user/visitor to the `next_url` parameter value. Is that a solution to avoid the replication lag?

Comment: It's just a workaround. If it fits your needs, I think you could try with it and find optimal time of waiting in your "redirector". But I personally would bet on fixing the problem instead using a workaround. If its impossible to avoid write/read combo by design, probably it makes sense to consider make all requests (both read and write) to master under specific conditions. For example, on the routes where users changes the data and need to get the results immediately, use the different connection with master only.